# Write in Windows-Eventlog with Delphi Event-ID not found

Tags: windows, delphi, event-log

I am writing a Service application for Windows in Delphi. On some events I write messages to the Windows EventLog. That works, but there is the following text in every log entry:

> The description for Event ID xxx from source yyyyy cannot be found...

I don't want this.

What I have done:

1. generate an ResouceEventlog.mc with this content:

   ```
   SeverityNames=(Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
                  Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
                  Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
                  Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
                 )

   FacilityNames=(System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
                  Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
                  Stubs=0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
                  Io=0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
                 )

   LanguageNames=(German=0x407:MSG00407)

   MessageIdTypedef=WORD

   MessageID=0x1
   Symbolicname=CAT_ALL
   Language=German
   Allgemein
   .

   MessageID=0x2
   Symbolicname=CAT_CALL
   Language=German
   Anruf
   .

   MessageID=0x3
   Symbolicname=CAT_LIC
   Language=German
   Lizenzinformation
   .

   MessageID=0x4
   Symbolicname=CAT_INFO
   Language=German
   Informationen
   .

   MessageID=0x5
   Symbolicname=CAT_ERR
   Language=German
   Fehler
   .

   MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

   MessageID=0x1000
   Symbolicname=LIC_INFO
   Language=German
   Lizenzinformationen
   .

   MessageID=0x1001
   Symbolicname=LIC_EXP
   Language=German
   Lizenzinformationen
   .

   MessageID=0x2000
   Symbolicname=CALL_SiG
   Language=German
   Anruf signalisieren
   .

   MessageID=0x2001
   Symbolicname=CALL_DBL
   Language=German
   Anruf bereits erfasst
   .

   MessageID=0x2002
   Symbolicname=CALL_CAPI
   Language=German
   Anruf an CAPI
   .

   MessageID=0x2003
   Symbolicname=CALL_PROCESS
   Language=German
   Anruf verarbeiten
   .

   MessageID=0x3000
   Symbolicname=ERR_CAPI
   Language=German
   Capi Fehler
   .

   MessageID=0x3001
   Symbolicname=ERR_PATH
   Language=German
   Speicherpfad kann nicht erstellt weren
   .

   MessageID=0x3002
   Symbolicname=ERR_NOCAPI
   Language=German
   Keine CAPI gefunden
   .

   MessageID=0x3003
   Symbolicname=ERR_UDP
   Language=German
   UDP_Empfangs_Port ist 0

   .
   ```
2. Compile `ResourceEventlog.mc` with `mc.exe`
3. Compile `RecourceEventLog.rc` with `brcc32.exe` to `ResourceEventlog.res`
4. Add `{$R RecourceEventlog.res}` to the main unit of my service application
5. in the `AfterInstall` event, I create some Registry entries:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Anrufmonitor]
   "EventMessageFile"="C:\\AM\\AMService.exe"
   "CategoryMessageFile"="C:\\AM\\AMService.exe"
   "CategoryCount"=dword:00000005
   "TypesSupported"=dword:00000007
   ```
6. in my Service application I define some constants and use `TService.LogEvent()` to write messages to the eventlog:

   ```
   const
     CAT_ALL      :WORD    =$1;
     CAT_CALL     :WORD    =$2;
     CAT_LIC      :WORD    =$3;
     CAT_INFO     :WORD    =$4;
     CAT_ERR      :WORD    =$5;
     LIC_INFO     :DWORD   =$00001000;
     LIC_EXP      :DWORD   =$00001001;
     CALL_SIG     :DWORD   =$00002000;
     CALL_DBL     :DWORD   =$00002001;
     CALL_CAPI    :DWORD   =$00002002;
     CALL_PROCESS :DWORD   =$00002003;
     ERR_CAPI     :DWORD   =$00003000;
     ERR_PATH     :DWORD   =$00003001;
     ERR_NOCAPI   :DWORD   =$00003002;
     ERR_UDP      :DWORD   =$00003003;

   ...
   LogMessage('test an eventlog-entry', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, CAT_CALL, CALL_PROCESS);
   ```

The eventlog entry is created successfully, but the "Event ID cannot be found" text still appears.

Comment: Did you restart the Event Viewer since adding the registry keys?

Comment: No.
I has test your idea, but i get the same result.

Comment: I will hope the eventlog use DWORD to get the MessageID from then resource. I have defined as DWORD in mc-file an in unit too.
But then eventlog display in the evententry alway integer. So i don't know if is it right, but i think so.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/166902/howto-troubleshooting-the-event-message-not-found-message) is about the IDs in point 5.

Answer (score 3):

None of your messages in the `.mc` file are specifying a `Severity` or `Facility`. The default `Severity` is `Success`, which is in your `SeverityName` list, but the default `Facility` is `Application` (`0xFFF`), which is not in your `FacilityNames` list.

A message's `Severity` and `Facility` numbers are included as part of the final resource ID number that is stored in the compiled message resource.  That is the number which must be passed to [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx) (wrapped by `TService.LogMessage()`) in its `dwEventID` parameter so it can find the correct resource string.  The exact format of that parameter is documented on MSDN:

[Event Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363651.aspx)

```
 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
+---+-+-+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
|Sev|C|R|     Facility          |               Code            |
+---+-+-+-----------------------+-------------------------------+

Sev

    Severity. The severity is defined as follows:

        00 - Success
        01 - Informational
        10 - Warning
        11 - Error

C

    Customer bit. This bit is defined as follows:

        0 - System code
        1 - Customer code

R

    Reserved bit.

Facility

    Facility code. This value can be FACILITY_NULL.

Code

    Status code for the facility.
```

This is also covered on MSDN Support:

[HOWTO: Troubleshooting the "Event Message Not Found" Message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/166902/howto-troubleshooting-the-event-message-not-found-message)

> 5. Make sure the correct ID is passed to the ReportEvent function.
>
> **Many think that the literal ID number found in the .mc file is the correct ID. This is not so** because the message compiler bitwise ORs the ID number into the LOWORD and bitwise ORs the severity and facility bits into the HIWORD. An application should always use the symbolic name in the header file that is output from the message compiler.
>
> Verify the MessageIdTypedef= statement in the .mc file. Some example .mc files show how to define the MessageIDTypedef to WORD for Category IDs. However, this causes Event IDs to loose the HIWORD. To correct this issue, define MessageIdTypedef= only once and set it to DWORD.
>
> Also be sure that the MC -c command line is consistently used for the message resources and header file. The -c switch turns on a bit in the HIWORD of the message ID.

The `-c` switch of [`mc.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385638.aspx) causes it to "*set the customer bit (bit 28) in all message IDs.*"

However, your Delphi constants are not accounting for this format.

For example, your `.mc` file defines `CALL_PROCESS` with a `MessageID` (the `Code` above) of `0x2003` and no `Severity` or `Facility`, so `Success=0x0` and `Application=0xFFF` are used, respectively.  Thus, the actual EventID for `CALL_PROCESS` is `0x2FFF2003` (you can verify this by looking at the compiled message resource with any Resource viewer/editor tool).

But, your Delphi code is defining `CALL_PROCESS` as `$00002003`, which is NOT the correct number that you need to pass to `LogMessage()`!

The same applies to all of your other message EventIDs (`LIC_INFO` through `ERR_UDP`).

The `MessageID` of a message's [category identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363649.aspx) is used as-is, so those category constants in your Delphi code (`CAT_ALL` through `CAT_ERR`) are fine.

Try this instead:

```
const
  CAT_ALL      :WORD    =$1;
  CAT_CALL     :WORD    =$2;
  CAT_LIC      :WORD    =$3;
  CAT_INFO     :WORD    =$4;
  CAT_ERR      :WORD    =$5;

  LIC_INFO     :DWORD   =$2FFF1000;
  LIC_EXP      :DWORD   =$2FFF1001;
  CALL_SIG     :DWORD   =$2FFF2000;
  CALL_DBL     :DWORD   =$2FFF2001;
  CALL_CAPI    :DWORD   =$2FFF2002;
  CALL_PROCESS :DWORD   =$2FFF2003;
  ERR_CAPI     :DWORD   =$2FFF3000;
  ERR_PATH     :DWORD   =$2FFF3001;
  ERR_NOCAPI   :DWORD   =$2FFF3002;
  ERR_UDP      :DWORD   =$2FFF3003;
```

Even if you fix your `.mc` file to explicitly specify correct `Severity` and `Facility` values for each message, make sure you also account for the Customer bit in your Delphi constants.

For example, if you set each message's `Facility` to 0x0, the correct EventIDs would look like this:

```
const
  CAT_ALL      :WORD    =$1;
  CAT_CALL     :WORD    =$2;
  CAT_LIC      :WORD    =$3;
  CAT_INFO     :WORD    =$4;
  CAT_ERR      :WORD    =$5;

  LIC_INFO     :DWORD   =$20001000;
  LIC_EXP      :DWORD   =$20001001;
  CALL_SIG     :DWORD   =$20002000;
  CALL_DBL     :DWORD   =$20002001;
  CALL_CAPI    :DWORD   =$20002002;
  CALL_PROCESS :DWORD   =$20002003;
  ERR_CAPI     :DWORD   =$20003000;
  ERR_PATH     :DWORD   =$20003001;
  ERR_NOCAPI   :DWORD   =$20003002;
  ERR_UDP      :DWORD   =$20003003;
```

And then, if you set the `Severity` to `Error` on the error messages, the correct EventIDs would look like this:

```
const
  CAT_ALL      :WORD    =$1;
  CAT_CALL     :WORD    =$2;
  CAT_LIC      :WORD    =$3;
  CAT_INFO     :WORD    =$4;
  CAT_ERR      :WORD    =$5;

  LIC_INFO     :DWORD   =$20001000;
  LIC_EXP      :DWORD   =$20001001;
  CALL_SIG     :DWORD   =$20002000;
  CALL_DBL     :DWORD   =$20002001;
  CALL_CAPI    :DWORD   =$20002002;
  CALL_PROCESS :DWORD   =$20002003;
  ERR_CAPI     :DWORD   =$E0003000;
  ERR_PATH     :DWORD   =$E0003001;
  ERR_NOCAPI   :DWORD   =$E0003002;
  ERR_UDP      :DWORD   =$E0003003;
```

So, defining the EventID constants correctly makes a BIG difference in whether `ReportEvent()` can find them in the message resource.