# Create a custom EventLog other than on the Application node in the Windows EventLog (in Delphi)

Tags: delphi, custom-eventlog

How create (in Delphi) a custom EventLog other than on the "Application" node in the Windows EventLog?

```
//The code below write on the Application node only

with TEventLogger.Create('JarvisAgent') do
begin
  try
    try
      LogMessage(Msg, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 2);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEventLogger` uses the older [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx) API for logging messages. For that API, you have to register a custom log file and its supported event source names, event types, etc in the Registry. Then you can create `TEventLogger` using your registered event source name, and messages will go to your registered log file.

This is all documented on MSDN.

[About Event logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363632.aspx)

[Event Logging Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363653.aspx)

Also see:

[Write in Windows-Eventlog with Delphi Event-ID not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181193/)

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417612/65863) to [WinAPI ReportEvent - component not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416970/).